# Tableau date math with multiple dates

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table of policies with account number, effective, cancellation & expiration dates. I want to know how long an account had active policies for

Raw Table

```
id, account_id, effective_date, cancellation_date, expiration_date
1, a, 2020-01-01, null, 2020-06-01
2, b, 2020-02-01, null, 2020-07-01
3, b, 2020-03-01, null, 2020-08-01
4, a, 2020-04-01, null, 2020-09-01
5, b, 2020-04-01, 2020-08-15, 2020-09-01
```

Ideal output

```
account_id, active_date, inactive_date, active_time
a, 2020-01-01, 2020-09-01, 9 months
b, 2020-02-01, 2020-08-15, 7 months 15 days
```

So far I have made a table that has account_id as the left hand column. And then I have
`MIN(effective_date)` to get me the active date of the first policy.

Then I have `Policy_Inactive_Date = MIN(cancellation_date, expiration_date)`. But that gives me the time the first policy was expired or cancelled.

It feels like I need to do MAX(Policy_Inactive_Date) but that throws and error.

I'm wondering if at first I need to get Policy_Inactive_Date at the policy level, and then get the max at the account level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like that

[image: Result preview]

**`active_dt`** field like this

```
{
    Fixed [account_id]: MIN([effective_date])
}
```

**`inactive_dt`** like this

```
{
    Fixed [account_id]:MAX(IF ISNULL(MIN([cancellation_date],[expiration_date])) then [expiration_date] else MIN([cancellation_date],[expiration_date]) END)
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I didn't know about `Fixed`. That is going to solve a lot of my problems!

Answer (score 0):

Try `MAX(MIN(cancellation_date, expiration_date))`

There are two forms of MIN() -- and two forms of MAX(). With one argument, MIN() is an aggregation function, returning the least non-null value of that argument for a set of records. With two arguments, MIN() evaluates each argument and returns the smallest of those two values.